# Convert a String To Integer From File Located on SD Card

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I am having a problem converting strings to integers so I can perform math functions. I have read about `str()` and `int()` but it doesn't seem to work here. I am trying to save data from one program to a file located on my Raspberry Pi 2 SD card using the code shown below; problem area is noted in CAPS near the bottom. I learned all data getting saved to the file are in string format. So no problem, just convert it back to an integer when I get the following error message:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

I tried Python versions 2 and 3 on my Raspberry Pi 2. The reason for this is that I have a counter in my main program that I want to update with its last position in the event of loss of power to the Raspberry Pi.

I have been pulling my hair out on this. Can someone please help me find the answer. I have been unable to find it myself on the internet, or in two Python books I purchased.

```
from __future__  import print_function
import datetime   #date and time library
# We begin by creating the file and writing some data.
webcam_home = open("home.txt", "a")
n = 1
m = 10
for i in range(0,5):
    n = n*10
    m = m*2
    webcam_home.write(str(n))
    webcam_home.write("%s\n" % m)  
webcam_home.close()

# Now, we open the file and read the contents printing out
# those rows that have values in 

webcam_home = open("home.txt", "r")

rows = webcam_home.readlines();
for row in rows:
    print(">", row)
    A = row
    print("6",int("A")+1,"abc")

webcam_home.close()
```

Comment: Try `int(A.rstrip())` instead of `int("A")`.  `"A"` is *not* a valid literal for `int()` with base 10.

Comment: You are trying to convert the string "A" to an integer.  What do you expect the value to be?  That function converts a number string to an integer (something like "123").

Comment: zondo, I just tried int(A.rstrip()) and it returns INTEGER CONVERTED FROM A STRING=.mp
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here... but why are you doing `int("A")` if you want the int / number of the row you could you could do `for i, row in enumerate(rows)` and just use `i +1` assuming you dont want a zero base in which case `i`. If you really need the integer value of the character `"A"` for whatever reason you could do `ord("A")`

Comment: Slayer, I am just trying to pull anything back in from my file and perform math with it. When I look in the file I see the numbers (that are strings) but I can not pull them back into the program and perform any math operations.

Comment: Mathew, I expect 'A' to to have the same value as 'row' which appears as a number if I look in the file (but I know it is a string). When I pull that string into the program and set it equal to 'A', I can print 'A' as a string just fine, just can't convert it to an integer.

Comment: if you want to get integer from string in row, you just need to do int(A) instead of int("A")

Comment: L.Kolar, I tried that and get the same error. Tried it with no quotes, double quotes and single quotes - no change.

Comment: I ran your code with line print("6",int("A")+1,"abc") replaced with print("6",int(A)+1,"abc") and got no errors.

Comment: If your lines contain two numbers, use the split function

Comment: L. Kolar, I wish I knew what you are doing different than I am but I tried it again and got the same error.

Comment: Traceback (most rect call last): File "test.py", line 27, in <module> print("6",int(A)+1,"abc") ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '  The error message is with no quotes around the A.

Comment: if I put single or double quotes around the A I get the same message except at the end it says ...with base 10: 'A'

Comment: Could I be missing an import of something to make these functions work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my problem:  **I ran your code with line print("6",int("A")+1,"abc") replaced with print("6",int(A)+1,"abc") and got no errors. – L. Kolar**

My issue was a corrupted SD Card. I replaced it with my back up and tried what L.Kolar said and life is good again. It worked! I spent waaaay too many hours getting to this point and thank everyone who tried to help me, with special thanks to L.Kolar.

I did some work on trying to get MySQL running and think I must have altered something to corrupt my SD card during the process.